# Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-unittest, relative-import

Here is my folder structure:

```
Mopy/ # no init.py !
   bash/
     __init__.py
     bash.py # <--- Edit: yep there is such a module too
     bass.py
     bosh/
       __init__.py # contains from .. import bass
       bsa_files.py
     ...
   test_bash\
     __init__.py # code below
     test_bosh\
       __init__.py
       test_bsa_files.py
```

In `test_bash\__init__.py` I have:

```
import sys
from os.path import dirname, abspath, join, sep
mopy = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
assert mopy.split(sep)[-1].lower() == 'mopy'
sys.path.append(mopy)
print 'Mopy folder appended to path: ', mopy
```

while in `test_bsa_files.py`:

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase

import bosh

class TestBSAHeader(TestCase):
    def test_read_header(self):
        bosh.bsa_files.Header.read_header()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now when I issue:

```
python.exe "C:\_\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py" C:\path\to\Mopy\test_bash\test_bosh\test_bsa_files.py true
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\_\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 124, in <module>
    modules = [loadSource(a[0])]
  File "C:\_\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 43, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces\python\wrye-bash\Mopy\test_bash\test_bosh\test_bsa_files.py", line 4, in <module>
    import bosh
  File "C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces\python\wrye-bash\Mopy\bash\bosh\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .. import bass
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

Since 'Mopy" is in the sys.path and `bosh\__init__.py` is correctly resolved why it complains about relative import above the top level package ? *Which is the top level package* ?

Incidentally this is my attempt to add tests to a legacy project - had asked in [Python test package layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34694437/281545) but was closed as a duplicate of [Where do the Python unit tests go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61151/281545). Comments on my current test package layout are much appreciated !

---

Well the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40022629/281545) does not work in my case:

The *module* bash.py is the entry point to the application containing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I use `import bash.bosh` or `from bash import bosh` I get:

```
C:\_\Python27\python.exe "C:\_\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py" C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces\python\wrye-bash\Mopy\test_bash\test_bosh\test_bsa_files.py true
Testing started at 3:45 PM ...
usage: utrunner.py [-h] [-o OBLIVIONPATH] [-p PERSONALPATH] [-u USERPATH]
                   [-l LOCALAPPDATAPATH] [-b] [-r] [-f FILENAME] [-q] [-i]
                   [-I] [-g GAMENAME] [-d] [-C] [-P] [--no-uac] [--uac]
                   [--bashmon] [-L LANGUAGE]
utrunner.py: error: unrecognized arguments: C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces\python\wrye-bash\Mopy\test_bash\test_bosh\test_bsa_files.py true

Process finished with exit code 2
```

This usage message is from the main() in bash.

Comment: Do you have any unguarded code in `bash.py` working with `sys.argv` or `argparse`? The `if __name__ == '__main__':` will not trigger on `import bash` or any of its variants.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Yep you got it - this line here parses the cli: https://github.com/wrye-bash/wrye-bash/blob/f739aba0aa09e4c1e12141bd9fcd268f760121c9/Mopy/bash/bash.py

Comment: You should move that one to `if __name__ ...`, though it will not fix the problem. I've updated the answer, giving the package higher priority over its modules.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

TLDR: Do

```
import bash.bosh
```

or

```
from bash import bosh
```

Avoid modifying `sys.path`, as this duplicates modules.

---

When you do

```
import bosh
```

it will import the *module* `bosh`. This means `Mopy/bash` is in your `sys.path`, python finds the file `bosh` there, and imports it. The module is now globally known by the name `bosh`. Whether `bosh` is itself a module or package doesn't matter for this, it only changes whether `bosh.py` or `bosh/__init__.py` is used.

Now, when `bosh` tries to do

```
from .. import bass
```

this is *not* a file system operation ("one directory up, file bass") but a module name operation. It means "one package level up, module bass". `bosh` wasn't imported from its package, but on its own, though. So going up one package is not possible - you end up at the package `''`, which is not valid.

Let's look at what happens when you do

```
import bash.bosh
```

instead. First, the *package* `bash` is imported. Then, `bosh` is imported as a module *of that package* - it is globally know as `bash.bosh`, even if you used `from bash import bosh`.

When `bosh` does

```
from .. import bass
```

that one works now: going one level up from `bash.bosh` gets you to `bash`. From there, `bass` is imported as `bash.bass`.

Comment: I had tried that btw and I had got the message but I did not mention (along with countless other such hit in the dark)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D You have duplicate names in your file hierarchy and think that might not be worth mentioning? oO Let me see if I can figure that one out...

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Added a piece for changing the preference of module vs package code. Give it a shot.

Comment: Nope :( exact same behavior as with `append` - still I see the usage() from bash.main() (hahaha, I mean, and imagine we even have a custom loader - not the simplest package structure in the world...)

Comment: Wait wait - let's move this inside test_bsa_files - edit: yep that worked !!! I did it cause I noticed that the debug print ('print 'Mopy folder appended to path: ', mopy` was not seen in the last output - the one with usage()). But why is not the `test_bash\__init__.py` run in this case ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D When you are running just `test_bosh\test_bar.py` directly, that has the same issue - never going through its parent package `test_bosh`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to hack or research the importing of the sibling module.
Simply go to your project directory and import the module. If project directory is not a package, add **init**.py to make it a project directory.

```
# File name ProjectDir/sibling1/main.py
import ProjectDir.sibling2

if __name__=='__main__':
    md = sibling2.module()
```

Comment: You can repeat the depth of modules and child modules. E.g.
`import ProjectDir.sibling2.submodule.subsubmodule ...`