# How to import from a sibling directory in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror, siblings

I have the following file structure:

```
bot
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── bot.py # <-- file that is executed from command line
├── plugins
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── debug.py
│   └── parsemessages.py
├── helpers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── parse.py
│   └── greetings.py
└── commands
    ├── __init__.py
    └── search.py
```

`bot.py`, when executed from the command line, will load in everything in the `plugins` directory.

I want `plugins/parsemessages.py` to import `parse` from the `helpers` directory, so I do that:

```
# parsemessages.py
from ..helpers import parse
parse.execute("string to be parsed")
```

I run `python3 bot.py` from the command line.

I get the following error:

```
File "/home/bot/plugins/parsemessages.py", line 2, in <module>
  from ..helpers import parse
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

So I change two dots to one:

```
# parsemessages.py
from .helpers import parse
parse.execute("string to be parsed")
```

...but I get another error:

```
File "/home/bot/plugins/parsemessages.py", line 2, in <module>
  from .helpers import parse
ImportError: No module named 'plugins.helpers'
```

How can I get this import to work?

It's worth noting that I'm not attempting to make a package here, this is just a normal script. That being said, I'm not willing to mess around with `sys.path` - I want this to be clean to use.

Additionally, I want `parse` to be imported as `parse` - so for the example above, I should be typing `parse.execute()` and not `execute()`.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022220/attempted-relative-import-beyond-toplevel-package) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import), but they start with a file that's quite deep in the file structure (mine is right at the top). I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports/50193944#50193944), but it seems to be talking about a package rather than just a regular .py.

What's the solution here?

Comment: `from . import foo`?

Comment: Does it work if you put a `__init__.py` in your top-level directory?

Comment: @hd1: `from . import parse` results in `ImportError: cannot import name 'parse'`

Comment: @jnrbsn: Sadly it does not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944/674039 is the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could remove the dots, and it should work:

```
# parsemessages.py
from helpers import parse
parse.execute("string to be parsed")
```

That's probably your best solution if you really don't want to make it a package. You could also nest the entire project one directory deeper, and call it like `python3 foo/bot.py`.

**Explanation:**

When you're not working with an actual installed package and just importing stuff relative to your current working directory, everything in that directory is considered a top-level package. In your case, `bot`, `plugins`, `helpers`, and `commands` are all top-level packages/modules. Your current working directory *itself is **not** a package*.

So when you do ...

```
from ..helpers import parse
```

... `helpers` is considered a top-level package, because it's in your current working directory, and you're trying to import from one level higher than that (*from* your current working directory *itself*, which is not a package).

When you do ...

```
from .helpers import parse
```

... you're importing relative to `plugins`. So `.helpers` resolves to `plugins.helpers`.

When you do ...

```
from helpers import parse
```

... it finds `helpers` as a top-level package because it's in your current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute your code from the root, my best answer to this is adding to the Path your root folder with os.getcwd().
Be sure your sibling folder has a **init**.py file.

```python
import os
os.sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())

from sibling import module
```